# Calculate Expected Values in Poisson Distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

[image]

What I have done so far:

I have found that $ Pr(X=3)= 0.0934 $ because the sum of probabilities equals $ 1.$
The mean I found in the previous question which was $ 1.34615 $.
When I plug in mean $ = 1.34615 $ and $ x=0 $, get that $ P(X=0) = 0.26024. $

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What "previous question" are you talking about? Why is it relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$, so $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}=0.2865$ implies $\lambda=-\log(0.2865)=1.25$. Indeed:
\begin{align*}P(X=0)&=e^{-\lambda}=e^{-1.25}=0.2865\\P(X=1)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda}=1.25e^{-1.25}=0.3581\\P(X=2)&=\frac{\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}}{2!}=\frac{1.25^2e^{-1.25}}{2}=0.2238
\end{align*}
and $P(X=3)=\frac{\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda}}{3!}=\frac{1.25^3 e^{-1.25}}{6}=0.0933$.

$\lambda$ is the average number of events in an interval, i.e.:
$$\frac{0\times 77+1\times 90+2\times 55+3\times 30+4\times y+5\times 3}{77+90+55+30+y+5}=1.25$$
therefore $y=5$ and $\lambda=\frac{325}{260}$.

As to the expected values, you have 325 events in 260 days, and $\lambda=1.25$ is *the* expected value (the mean) of this Poisson distribution (the average number of events in one day), but the expected *values* (plural) are the number of days with $X=0,1,2,3,\dots$ events out of 260:
\begin{align*} X=0: &\quad P(X=0)\times 260=0.2865\times 260=74.5\\X=2: &\quad P(X=2)\times 260=0.2238\times 260=58.2\\X=4: &\quad P(X=4)\times 260=0.0291\times 260=7.6\\X=5: &\quad P(X=5)\times 260=0.0073\times 260=1.9\end{align*}
Furthermore, $P(X\ge 6)=1-P(X=0)-\cdots-P(X=5)=0.0018$ and $0.0018\times 260=0.5$.

Finally, \begin{align*}E_1&=P(X=1)\times 260=0.3581\times 260=93.1\\E_3&=P(X=3)\times 260=0.0933\times 260=24.3\end{align*}